# Visual Studio 2019 .net core web api will only use developer ssl cert

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ssl, .net-core, localhost

I am running a .NET core web api on my local machine.  I have an ssl certificate for the machine, but when I try and run the app pointing to the hostname of the machine, I get an error NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID because it is defaulting to the localhost development certificate instead of using the actual certificate for the machine.  It works fine when I do run it as localhost, but I need to be able to view the api from other machines so localhost is not an option.

I have tried reinstalling Visual Studio and reinstalling the certificate.

This is my launchsettings.json file.

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iis": {
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:44349/",
      "sslPort": 0
    },
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:44349/",
      "sslPort": 44349
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "QiApi": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "applicationUrl": "https://xxxxx.xxxx.utah.edu:44349/"
    }
  }
}

This is the program.cs file

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var host = new WebHostBuilder()
                .UseKestrel()
                .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .UseIISIntegration()
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                .Build();
            host.Run();
        }
```

Comment: the host name you are trying to access is it the same as the one in your ssl cert? where did you get that ssl cert? self signed or from CA? is DNS properly pointing the right machine? did you setup the cert in your IIS binding?

Comment: The host name is the same and the cert if from CA.  The dns is pointing to the right machine and the cert is setup in IIS.